# How to change font of default header and footer of print page with css?

Tags: html, css

How can i change font of **default** header and footer of print page with css?

i tried this:

```
   @media print
    {
        *,html,body,title /*i tried all of them!*/
        {
            font: 10px tahoma;
        }
    }
```

the content of page was changed
but no change was happened in font of print page title, url and pagination.(ctrl+p)

[this is my print page image to clear my question](http://s4.picofile.com/file/8172065684/q.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can not be changed, it's not part of the web page itself.